# Flutter: how to disable the scroll to the left in pageview?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-pageview

and today when I am developing my app, I just find out that I need a feature that can only allow user to scroll to the **right** page, but not the **left** page, and the PageController does not provide any functionality that can allow me to implement that, so that's the reason why I am here!

I also visited this link:

[StackOverflow: Custom ScrollPhysics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55504170/14930256), but it does not contain any explanation, you know it's painful to use other people's code without knowing what it is doing, right? So please help me!!! ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own `ScrollPhysics` to lock the scroll to a direction, or you can use the [horizontal_blocked_scroll_physics](https://pub.dev/packages/horizontal_blocked_scroll_physics) lib to help you.

Here is an example of a `CustomScrollPhysic` that enable only right scrolling

```
class CustomScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  CustomScrollPhysics({ScrollPhysics parent}) : super(parent: parent);

  bool isGoingLeft = false;

  @override
  CustomScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics ancestor) {
    return CustomScrollPhysics(parent: buildParent(ancestor));
  }

  @override
  double applyPhysicsToUserOffset(ScrollMetrics position, double offset) {
    isGoingLeft = offset.sign < 0;
    return offset;
  }

  @override
  double applyBoundaryConditions(ScrollMetrics position, double value) {
    assert(() {
      if (value == position.pixels) {
        throw FlutterError(
          '$runtimeType.applyBoundaryConditions() was called redundantly.\n'
          'The proposed new position, $value, is exactly equal to the current position of the '
          'given ${position.runtimeType}, ${position.pixels}.\n'
          'The applyBoundaryConditions method should only be called when the value is '
          'going to actually change the pixels, otherwise it is redundant.\n'
          'The physics object in question was:\n'
          '  $this\n'
          'The position object in question was:\n'
          '  $position\n');
      }
      return true;
    }());
    if (value < position.pixels && position.pixels <= position.minScrollExtent)
      return value - position.pixels;
    if (position.maxScrollExtent <= position.pixels && position.pixels < value)
      return value - position.pixels;
    if (value < position.minScrollExtent &&
        position.minScrollExtent < position.pixels)

      return value - position.minScrollExtent;

    if (position.pixels < position.maxScrollExtent &&
        position.maxScrollExtent < value)
      return value - position.maxScrollExtent;

    if (!isGoingLeft) {
      return value - position.pixels;
    }
    return 0.0;
  }
}
```

You can use as the example below, `CustomScrollPhysics` as value to physics parameter.

```
PageView.builder(
  physics: CustomScrollPhysics(),
);
```

Some references that could explain better how ScrollPhysics works

- [Flutter Doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics-class.html)
- [David Anaya's Medium article](https://medium.com/koahealth/custom-scroll-physics-in-flutter-3224dd9e9b41)

Comment: Very appreciate your response, but do you have a way to solve my case without adding a new package, because my app is already 200 mb large in size, and afraid to add a new package... @_@

Comment: I added a new code example! I think it could help you

Comment: Yes, thank you for the patient, but an explanation for it will be nice, or do you know any tutorials about this, so that I can dive deep into the codes of how it works? :)

Comment: You're welcome! I've added some references that could explain better the behavior of the `ScrollPhysics`. The main function of this code is `applyBoundaryConditions`, it validates if the user can scroll or not, using the position and the scroll value as parameter to evaluate.